# How to create dropdown list in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Since i have never used a drop down list in MVC before, I am having problems creating one.
I have looked it up but i am not understanding. I want to create a basic drop down list for "Gender" in MVC3.

So far i have been able to create this.

Class:

```
    public Dictionary<int, string> Gender {get;set; }  
    public StudentInformation()
    {

    Gender = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
            { 0, "Male"},
            { 1, "Female"},

        };
}
```

View:

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender.Keys,
                     new SelectList(
                         Model.Gender, 
                         "Key", 
                         "Value"))
```

But it throws an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of the object".

Comment: Please show your effort. What have you tried? Some code...

Comment: Check now i have edited it.

Comment: You're getting a NullReferenceException, this should be very easy for you to debug. Is Model null?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a bunch of different ways.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this,

```
public class Blog {
    private readonly IList<Post> _list = new List<Post> {
        new Post(1, "How to 1"),
        new Post(2, "How to 2"),
        new Post(3, "How to 3"),
        new Post(4, "How to 4"),
        new Post(5, "How to 5")
    };


    public SelectList Posts {
        get {
            return new SelectList(_list, "PostId", "Title");
        }
    }

    public int? SelectedPostId { get; set; }
}

public class Post {
    public Post(int postId, string title) {
        PostId = postId;
        Title = title;
    }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

//The View:
@Html.DropDownFor(o => o.SelectedPostId, Model.Posts)
```

Here is the link for more of explanations:

[Reference](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: There's a small typo in the view code (the name of the helper). Other than that this is the most correct approach using a view model (compared to the other answers).

Comment: check my question i have edited it and tell me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try This....

Controller

```
 var value = new SelectList(new[]
                {
                    new {ID="1",Name="ISO 9001"},
                    new{ID="2",Name="BIS Hallmark"},
                    new{ID="3",Name="ISI"},
                });
                ViewData["values "] = value
```

VIEW

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Cert", (SelectList)ViewData["Certification"], "--Select--", new { @class="dropdownlist" ,id = "Cert" })
```

Comment: Aside from your code sample not even matching the poster's original code/model, this won't even work. You're setting the ViewData with one key and then trying to retrieve it with a different key.